# Differential equation and parametric integrals

Tags: calculus

> **10.22** Let $F(y)$ be defined by $$F(y)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(2xy) \,\mathrm dx$$ for $y\in\Bbb R$. Show that $F$ satisfies the differential equation $$F'(y)+2yF(y)=0$$
>    and deduce that $F(y)=\frac 12\sqrt{\pi} \ e^{-y^2}$. (Use the result $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \,\mathrm dx =\pi/2$$ derived in Exercise 7.19.

I am having some trouble doing this exercise. Can someone help me out? I cannot figure it out how to prove that the differential equation equals $0$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this integral is convergent so we use partial integration to show that 
$$
\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(2xy)dx=-\frac{1}{2y}
\int_{0}^\infty 2x e^{-x^2}\sin(2xy)dx
$$
Next, we note that we can take derivative inside integral since the derivative of the integrand is improper Riemann integrable on $[0,\infty)$, so $$F'(y)=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial y} e^{-x^2}\cos(2xy)dx=\int_{0}^\infty 2xe^{-x^2}\sin(2xy) dx$$

It readily follows that $F'(y)+2yF(y)=0$.
Which can be rewritten as 
$$
F'(y)=-2y F(y)
$$

Using that $$F(0)=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}$$
 The boundary conditions of this differential equation are $F(0)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}$. Then, $$F(y)=F(0)e^{-y^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}e^{-y^2}$$

Comment: Alright i understand everything except the last step , can you give me a hint?

Comment: If $f'(y)=-2yf(y)$ then $f(y)=C e^{-y^2}$ With $f(0)=C e^{0}=C$. In otter words $f(y)=f(0)e^{-y^2}$

Comment: yeah but i dont understand why

Comment: The derivative of $C e^{-y^2}=-2y C e^{-y^2}$, i.e. $f'(y)=-2yf(y)$

Comment: alright i got it , thx

Comment: Why do i need the boundary condition when im resolving this differential equation? Why cant the function just be e^(-y^2)?